# .NET timezone from environment variable

Tags: c#, timezone

I wish to set a 'Timezone' environment variable which will will be picked up by a .NET executable instead of the default one.

Specifically, `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone()` will return the overriding timezone info, and not the default.

I know this can be done in C++, using the ['TZ'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htb3tdkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) variable. Is it possible in .Net as well?

**Update**

Sorry for not being more clear about this: I do not have access to the source code. Basically, what I want is to run an executable, tricking it into thinking the timezone is other than the machine's default.

Comment: According to the docs that expression will always return the time zone specified in Windows' control panel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> Specifically, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone() will return the overriding timezone info, and not the default.

That's going to be tricky.

It's likely to be *much* less invasive to pass a system time zone ID around and use [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx). Then *explicitly* use that every time you need "the default time zone" rather than relying on the real system default one.

Basically you should abandon `TimeZone` as far as possible. It's very feature-poor compared with `TimeZoneInfo`. (Personally I'd abandon `TimeZoneInfo` as well and use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project but that's a slightly different matter ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) method allows you to retrieve the value of any environment variable from .NET code. However you must use an external mechanism to have the environment variable set in the frist place, also the value of the variable may be any string so you must validate the format of the obtained value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an environment variable using `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Timezone")` method.